# Unhexlify seems to give me an int when I want a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, xor, ord

I need to do an XOR of two hex strings so that each byte is XORed separately, but it doesn't work because the `ord()` function that I use seems to be getting an `int` as input instead of the intended string. Take a look at his code first to see what I mean:

```
from binascii import hexlify, unhexlify

def xor_hexstr(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) > len(s2):
        q = zip(unhexlify(s1[:len(s2)]), unhexlify(s2))
        return hexlify("".join(chr(ord(c1) ^ ord(c2)) for c1, c2 in q))

    else:
        q = zip(unhexlify(s2[:len(s1)]), unhexlify(s1))
        return hexlify("".join(chr(ord(c1) ^ ord(c2)) for c1, c2 in q))


t1 = "0ec17c9dabb8955c5dfb9cef627ddb4d"
t2 = "4ca00ff4c898d61e1edbf1800618fb28"

xor_hexstr(t1, t2)
```

And the error that I am getting:

```
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
```

I then checked the values of q, and they indeed where integers for some reason. I don't see why, because according to my logic they are supposed to be strings because I gave it a hex encoded string, unhexlified it and then stuck each character into a slot in q.

Comment: Why do you pass `s1`, `s2` instead of `t1`, `t2`?

Comment: Sorry falsetru, that was a typo :D. I don't have that in my original code though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `hexlify` and `unhexlify` on Python 3, where they return a `bytes` object. You then zip these objects, which iterates over the `bytes` objects to create the pairs. Iteration over a `bytes` object produces integers. See the [`bytes` type documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes):

> While `bytes` literals and representations are based on ASCII text, `bytes` objects actually behave like immutable sequences of integers, with each value in the sequence restricted such that `0 <= x < 256`.

You do not need to use `ord()` when looping over a `bytes` object; you *already* have integers representing the individual bytes.

Simply use a `bytes` object again after XOR-ing the values:

```
def xor_hexstr(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) > len(s2):
        q = zip(unhexlify(s1[:len(s2)]), unhexlify(s2))
    else:
        q = zip(unhexlify(s2[:len(s1)]), unhexlify(s1))

    return hexlify(bytes(c1 ^ c2 for c1, c2 in q))
```

Note that `hexlify` returns a `bytes` object too. If you *have* to have a string (unicode) object then decode from ASCII:

```
xor_hexstr(t1, t2).decode('ASCII')
```

Demo:

```
>>> xor_hexstr(t1, t2)
b'426173696320434243206d6f64652065'
>>> xor_hexstr(t1, t2).decode('ASCII')
'426173696320434243206d6f64652065'
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution worked, and your explanation was good :D.

Answer (score 0):

```
from binascii import hexlify, unhexlify

def xor_hexstr(s1, s2):
    q = zip(unhexlify(s1), unhexlify(s2))
    return "".join(chr(c1 ^ c2) for c1, c2 in q)


s1 = "0ec17c9dabb8955c5dfb9cef627ddb4d"
s2 = "4ca00ff4c898d61e1edbf1800618fb28"

print(xor_hexstr(s1, s2))
```

output `Basic CBC mode e`